# Displaying contents of doc file in jTextPane

Tags: java, swing, apache-poi, jtextpane

i m trying to display contents of a doc file into jTextPane. But it is displaying only the last line of document while on console it is displaying whole document.
I m using Apache POI library.

```
File file = null;
    WordExtractor extractor = null ;
    try {

        file = new File("C:\\Users\\Siddique Ansari\\Documents\\CV Parser\\Siddique_Resume.doc");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
        extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
        String [] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
        for(int i=0;i<fileData.length;i++){
            System.out.println(fileData[i]);
            jTextPane1.setText(fileData[i]);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception exep){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jTextPane1.setText(fileData[i]);` will override the current value each time.

Instead, append to the underlying document:

```
Document doc = jTextPane1.getDocument();

// ... in your loop:
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), fileData[i], null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
for(int i=0;i<fileData.length;i++){
    System.out.println(fileData[i]);
    jTextPane1.setText(fileData[i]);
}
```

try

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i < fileData.length; i++){
    System.out.println(fileData[i]);
    content.append(fileData[i]).append("\n");
    jTextPane1.setText(content.toString());
}
```

---

Also,

```
catch(Exception exep){}
```

is never a good idea. At least write:

```
catch(Exception exep) { exep.printStackTrace(); }
```

so you know what's going on when an excecption occurs.